# Generate cartesian product

Tags: string, bash, sh

I am trying to generate some strings like

```
AAAA0000
AAAA0001
...
..
...
ZZZZ9999
```

I can do it with below logic & it will work

```
   for A in {A..Z}
    do
        for B in {A..Z}
            do
                for C in {A..Z}
                    do
                    for D in {A..Z}
                        do
                        for E in {0..9}
                            do
                            for F in {0..9}
                                do
                                for G in {0..9}
                                    do
                                        for H in {0..9}
                                        do
                                            echo $A$B$C$D$E$F$G$H

                                        done
                                    done
                                done
                            done
                        done
                    done
                done
            done
        done
    done
```

This is exhausting way of doing it (Though it solves the problem)

Can anyone help in some efficient way of doing same

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}` ?

Comment: So cartesian product of sets can work here.. Thanks bash wizards. I was not knowing this

Comment: The numbers, at least, can be generate by a single loop `for E in {0000..9999}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine multiply bracket expansions with: `{A..Z}{A..Z}...`. But the cartesian product is above 4 billions combinations (`26 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10`), which will be stored in memory (Around 38 GB if not more).

You can however use Perl or similar to generate this list:

```
perl -le 'print for "AAAA0000" .. "ZZZZ9999"' > output.txt
```

<sup>Expect it to take some time</sup>
This will generate a file that is about 38 GB in size:

```
26 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * (8 + 1) = 41,127,840,000 bytes
^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^     ^   ^
A-Z  A-Z  A-Z  A-Z  0-9  0-9  0-9  0-9   |   new line
                                         8 bytes wide AAAA0000, AAAA0001, ...

41127840000 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 38.30 GB
^             ^      ^      ^
Bytes         KB     MB     GB
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
printf "%s\n" {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}
```

...

Hem, Of course, this may consume some memory!

This smaller form work on my computer:

```
printf "%s\n" {A..F}{A..F}{A..F}{A..F}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9} | wc 
12960000 12960000 116640000
```

Of course [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is no a programming language, but you could:

```
recurs () { 
    local level=$1 upper=$2;
    shift 2;
    ((level)) && { 
        for i in $@ ;do
            recurs $[level-1] $upper$i $@;
        done
    } || { 
        for i in $@ ;do
            echo $upper$i;
        done
    }
}
```

This will make recursion job:

```
recurs 3 '' a b c d e f | tee >(sed -ne '1p;$p') >(wc) >/dev/null ;sleep .2
aaaa
   1296    1296    6480
ffff
```

The second argument is *left part string*, so for doing thing like asked:

```
while read lhs ;do
    recurs 3 $lhs {0..4}
  done < <(
    recurs 3 '' {A..F}
) | tee >(sed -ne '1p;$p') >(wc) >/dev/null ;sleep .2
AAAA0000
 810000  810000 7290000
FFFF4444
```

And, if you really wanna see how quick could be bash:

```
time while read lhs ;do
    recurs 3 $lhs {0..9}
  done < <(
    recurs 3 '' {A..Z}
) | tee >(sed -ne '1p;$p') >(wc) >/dev/null ;sleep .2
```

Comment: I tried it on cygwin, it slowed my computer beyond measure and was consuming 9GB of memory when I killed it. Maybe it would work better on other systems but I would strongly advise to test it with smaller sets first.

Comment: @Aaron It will try to consume 38 GB of memory.

Comment: Of course `bash` is a programming language; it just isn't one suitable for data-intensive tasks.

Comment: You overusing process substitution. Instead of `tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2) >/dev/null`, just use `tee >(cmd1) | cmd2`.